# Black border around scaled strip with alpha over

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When downscaling a strip in the **VSE**, black borders appears around visible edge pixels.
This is noticeable when overlaying (*alpha over*) the strip into a lighter background.

In this example, a yellow color strip is scaled down. The *transform effects strip* is scaled down and the mode is set to *alpha over*. Below both is a white *color strip*. Dark borders are visible at the edge of the strip.
[image: black border around yellow color strip]

This is also the scale with scaled normal images.
[image]

Most solution to similiar posts ([this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92466/30849), [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31420/30849)) suggest using masks, which may work in some cases, but appears to be a workaround rather than a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform strip appears to not handle premultiplication/alpha over correctly with the *bilinear*.

No borders are visible with the **cubic** interpolation mode.

[image]